# How to put a css tag in an element if another has this element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div id="user_navigation" class="logged_in right">
   <ul class="ipsList_inline">
      <li><a data-clicklaunch="getNotificationsList" id="notify_link" href="http://localhost/joridesign/index.php?app=core&amp;module=usercp&amp;area=notificationlog" title="Notifications" class="ipbmenu menu-active"><i class="fa fa-bell fa-2x"></i></a>
       </li>
       <li><a data-clicklaunch="getInboxList" id="inbox_link" href="http://localhost/joridesign/index.php?app=members&amp;module=messaging" title="Messenger"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x"></i></a>
       </li>                   
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Okay i have this structure.
What i am trying to do if any of the two `li` inside the `ul` has the `menu-active` class the `#user_navigation .ipsList_inline li {}` will have a new class which is `background: #fff`;
i know there is a reason by jquery but i am asking is there is any other ways? if not can you show it to me through jquery?

Comment: Simple answer: you can't do this via CSS. You can't check for the contents of an element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way would be to just target any LI that contains that class, get it and the sibling LI's, and add a class (or css() as in the example, anything really)

```
$('li:has(.menu-active)').siblings('li').addBack().css('background', '#fff');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7MmLw/)

**EDIT :**

To change only the one that contains the class

```
$('.menu-active').closest('li').addClass('myClass');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7MmLw/1/)

Comment: Thanks alot it works but it changes the background for both of the li's i want only the li that has this css tag "menu-active"

Comment: That's not really how you described it in the question, but it makes it a whole lot easier

Answer (score 1):

Check element with `menu-active` exists, then add class or css to its `.closest()` *li*

```
var elem = $('#user_navigation .ipsList_inline li a.menu-active');
if (elem.length) {
    elem.closest('li').addClass('newClass')
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/vJtn3/3/)

Comment: Thanks alot it works but it changes the background for both of the li's i want only the li that has this css tag "menu-active"

Comment: Check my code bro, the menu-active is in the a not in the li

Comment: Thansk alot man that works

Comment: @AbdallahAbdalaziz, even simpler `$('#user_navigation .ipsList_inline li a.menu-active').closest('li').addClass('newClass')`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    if ( $( '#user_navigation .ipsList_inline li a' ).hasClass( "menu-active" ) ) {
$('#user_navigation .ipsList_inline li a.menu-active').parent().addClass( "newclass");
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LgKry/2/)

Comment: Thanks alot it works but it changes the background for both of the li's i want only the li that has this css tag "menu-active"

Comment: @AbdallahAbdalaziz i updated it